# How do I center view on my dwarves?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

So I pressed something and now I can't see my dwarves.  Is there a hot-key that centers my screen on my dwarves?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To view any particular dwarf use the <kbd>u</kbd>nits screen, select the dwarf you want and do a <kbd>c</kbd>reature zoom.

You can also setup hotkeys for a location with the <kbd>h</kbd>otkey screen. On the hotkey screen, press the appropriate function key (<kbd>F1</kbd>,<kbd>F2</kbd>, etc) and then press <kbd>z</kbd> to set the location to zoom to. You can optionally press <kbd>n</kbd> to name the location, which I find very useful.

[image: Hotkey Screenshot]

Comment: @CRoss good answer, but maybe you should explain how the hotkey screen works.  That (and maybe screenshots) would make this a Great answer.

Comment: @tzenes I'll try to do that, when I get home.